# Establishing uniform ellipticity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-differential-equations

Let $\mathbf{B}$ be a $m×n$ matrix ($m>n$) over $\mathbb{R}$ of the form
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B} =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{I}\\
\tilde{\mathbf{B}}
\end{array}
\right),
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix of size $n\times n$ and $\tilde{\mathbf{B}}$ of size $(m-n)\times n$. Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a square matrix of size $n\times n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\det{\mathbf{C}}\neq0$ and define $\mathbf{A}:=(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C})(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C})^\star$.

I have two questions regarding this setup:

(Q1) Is it possible for the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ to be uniformly elliptic? I.e. that for all vectors $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and some constant $\epsilon>0$, it holds that $y^\star A y \geq \epsilon |y|^2$.

(Q2) If that is the case, can one obtain conditions on the Frobenius norm of $\mathbf{B}^{-1}$ (the left inverse of $\mathbf{B}$) and $\mathbf{C}^{-1}$ which imply the uniform ellipticity of $\mathbf{A}$? (Akin to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584998/characterization-of-uniform-ellipticity) condition.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrix $A$ is symmetric. Accordingly, when $y$ is unit, all values of $y^* A y$ lie between the smallest eigenvalue and the largest eigenvalue of $A$. An overkill way of seeing this is to use the spectral theorem to conclude that the eigenvalues are real and to expand $y$ in an orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of $A$. You find that $y^* A y$ is a convex combination of the eigenvalues of $A$.

In this case because $A=D D^*$ for some $D$, $A$ is positive semidefinite by default, so the uniform ellipticity condition is precisely the question "is $A$ nonsingular?" Can you proceed from there, or do you need some more help deciding whether it is singular?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It seems to me that since $rank(\mathbf{B})=rank(\mathbf{C})=n$ it follows that also $rank(\mathbf{A})=n$. Hence $\mathbf{A}$ is singular and cannot be uniformly elliptic. Is that correct?

Comment: @user14502 Looks right to me.